# Problems with router configuration for sever client

Tags: java, networking, configuration, router

I'm working on a java project for some time now, the project contain a server and a program that connect to the server.
until 2 weeks ago, every thing worked fine, i could connect to the server from my own network ( that run the server) and from other network (WAN) as well.

2 weeks ago i provider network and got a different router from them, so as i did before i entered its settings and
opened the port for my program ( with port forwarding and all this..) how ever, it doesn't work well as it was before.

if I'm using the ip (from whatsMyIp) and put it in the client, i can enter to the server from other networks how ever I cant enter to it from my own computer that run the server.

if I'm using the ip (from ipconfig), i can enter the server from my own computer however other networks cant connect to 
my server.

(as i told before, all worked fine before i changed my router)

hope you can help me.. thanks

Comment: It's not programming related, it seems a problem of the router configuration. It would be a better fit for Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the server from outside your network using your public IP but not from a computer in your local network (using the same public IP) then check your router settings (firewall or port forwarding). There's probably a setting there allowing port forwarding only from your public interface and not from your private int.

Comment: I didn't find any setting in the port forwarding in my router settings that connect to this situation and after i kept searching all over the router settings and didn't find anything that may help fix this problem...  Maybe you can be more specific if you could.. (it would help)

Comment: If possible, here's a simple test you can try to test port forwarding.
Set up port forwarding for SSH pointing to one of your local pc. Then try to ssh (from another computer in your local net) using your public IP. If you can connect, then your router settings are correct.
For example, private network is 192.168.1.0/24, gateway is 192.168.1.1, ssh server is 192.168.1.2, some pc is 192.168.1.3 
And if your public ip is 5.5.5.5 then you would set port forwarding so any connection that tries to connect to 5.5.5.5:22 gets forwarded to 192.168.1.2:22
Then, from 192.168.1.3, connect to 5.5.5.5:22